# Create "printer" to print as PDF to SQL database

Tags: windows, printing, pdf-generation, driver

I would like to create a "printer" that would display as an available printer when a user tries to print a document.

If this printer is used, a window will be displayed showing the available locations in the database that the document can be stored.  The document will then be converted to PDF format and the resulting blob data will be inserted into the database.

I found a similar topic here: [How to create own XP printer driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067245/how-to-create-own-xp-printer-driver).  However, some of the answers suggest using RedMon (which does not look like it currently supports Windows 7).  The solution should be supported in Windows XP and up.

I thought I would start a new question to see if anybody has done anything more recently than that previous question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) installs a virtual printer that creates a PDF file, but it doesn't interact with databases as far as I know.

Comment: @KeithThompson, since PDFCreator is GNU licensed you can modify it to save the output to a database. Of course you'd have to make the enhancements public to stay within the terms of the license.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Good point.  (I *think* that applies only if you distribute the new version, but [IANAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need RedMon.  The top answer to the question you linked (the answer from Oleg) is precisely the answer to your question.  Just take the Port Monitor sample from the WDK and modify it to do as you need.  However, you will also need a print driver in order to create a printer.  For that you can use the Unidriver or Postscript drivers shipped with Windows.  All you'll need to provide is an .inf file that will install and name your printer appropriately and a .ppd or .gpd file to describe its characteristics.  Many examples of both can be found readily in the WDK or online.

Answer (score 0):

using pdfcreator or bullzip pdf as a printer to create a pdf file *in a folder* and then using use some folder watchers (like 'Watch4Folder') in order to trigger a script (to insert the file into a blob field), in a way that you can create several folders so you can customize the target database by choosing diferent folder where to "print" the pdf file.

Sorry for my english

Claudio